# Writing data into a text file using spark-submit does not work

Tags: apache, scala, hadoop

I have a set of data which is being expanded as per my requirement using spark. The expanded data (running in a loop) is to be written in a text file in HDFS and i am facing issues while doing so. Only the first two records are being written and it fails then on.

Below is the Code i am using to process and write into text file:

```
         def Hdfswrite(record:String)
        {
        //val timestamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH").format(new java.util.Date())
        val file = "/user/bhkp/sparkoutput6/sparkoutput12" + ".txt"
        val line = "\n" + record
        val config = new Configuration()
        val fs = FileSystem.get(config)
try
        {
        val writer = fs.append(new Path(file))
        writer.write(line.getBytes)
        writer.close
        }
        catch
        {
          case t: Throwable => { val writer = fs.create(new Path(file))
          writer.write(line.getBytes)
          writer.close
          }
        }
        }
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val tokenized = sc.textFile("/user/bhkp/hv_tables/sparktestdata12.txt").map(rec => (rec.split("\\^",-1)))
    tokenize.foreach(transfer)

  }
```

I am getting the following error :
**org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): ID mismatch. Request id and saved id.**

I am not sure where the issue is occurring since the data is getting written when the input file has only 2 records, but starts to fail when the record count is 3 or more.

When i try to print the output, it works perfectly fine.

I am confused.

Comment: can you be more clear. is it the exact code that you are running ?? what is transfer function ?. and its "tokenized" in "tokenize.foreach(transfer)"

Comment: The transfer function is used to expand the data. It loops through a file, fetches each row of data and process it and it works fine. I am calling the Hdfswrite function once each loop is completed to write the record.                                        Hdfswrite(record) .The above code in question is used for writing it in a text file.

Comment: Open and close the file on each record is a very bad Idea, and have to fail at least one time to create the file in the CATCH is very buggy. Remember that spark is running several tasks in parallel, Which of them will create the file the first time ? What will happen if two or more tasks try to create the file at the same time? Please review the Spark API and avoid to write your own writer. You can use flatMap over an RDD to expand your records and saveAsTextFile to write your output